# Persistent Audio Cracking issue present when using laptop speakers and wired headphones, but not bluetooth

Tags: sound, laptop, pipewire

I would like to thank you in advance for your help. So I have been having an issue with a persistent crackling sound when listening to any type of audio on my laptop running ubuntu 23.10. This issue was not present on ubuntu 22.04, which leads me to infer that this issue may be related to pipewire. I additionally have tried to infer that it possibly could be caused by a buffer-underrun issue. So things I have tried are modifying my pipewire.conf, specifically these lines:

```
   ## Properties for the DSP configuration.
default.clock.rate          = 48000
default.clock.allowed-rates = [ 44100 48000 ]
default.clock.quantum       = 4096
default.clock.min-quantum   = 1024
default.clock.max-quantum   = 8192
```

and disabling suspend in the wireplumber configuration, like this:

```
      ["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"] = 0,  -- 0 disables suspend
```

Lastly, here is the output from the inxi command:

```
System:
  Host: ubuntu Kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME
    v: 45.2 Distro: Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LG product: 15Z95N-G.AAC6U1 v: 0.1
    serial: 106NZWY052985
  Mobo: LG model: 15Z95N v: FAB1
    serial: E2DFC982AEDA2EB6ABC3D9B773836F2315Z95N-G.AAC6U1 UEFI: Phoenix
    v: T1ZF0282 X64 date: 02/21/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: CMB0 charge: 23.3 Wh (34.4%) condition: 67.8/80.0 Wh (84.8%)
    volts: 7.5 min: 7.7
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    cache: L2: 5 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 400 min/max: 400/4200 cores: 1: 400 2: 400 3: 400 4: 400
    5: 400 6: 400 7: 400 8: 400
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Chicony LG Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.23.2 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.0 driver:
    dri: iris gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1 renderer: Mesa Intel Xe
    Graphics (TGL GT2)
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.5.0-14-generic status: kernel-api
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: c4:23:60:3e:b9:49
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth driver: btusb type: USB
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes
    address: C4:23:60:3E:B9:4D
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 33.21 GiB (7.0%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: SK Hynix model: HFM512GD3JX013N
    size: 476.94 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 465.36 GiB used: 33.08 GiB (7.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1
  ID-2: /boot size: 1.9 GiB used: 130.9 MiB (6.7%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 1.05 GiB used: 6.1 MiB (0.6%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 4 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swap.img
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 38.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 302 Uptime: 22m Memory: total: 16 GiB available: 15.3 GiB
  used: 3.49 GiB (22.8%) igpu: 60 MiB Shell: Sudo inxi: 3.3.29
```

lastly, I thank you in advance for your help. I tried my best to include all the relevant information in this post, but if more information would be helpful, don't hesitate to let me know.